# Why did a moderator remove a whole sentence in my question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have often observed that some of my questions were revised by moderators, and till now I always understood (and approved) the reason of the modification: correcting typos or language faults, adapting title to be more descriptive, and so on.

But just now I faced a revision I can't understand.

My question text ended with asking visitors to send me feedback about how my code could be enhanced or corrected (last sentence in [this page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/92801/revisions)'s revision #5), and this sentence was removed!

I wondered if it could be due to the "thanks" which begins the sentence: I know we must avoid useless courtesy formulas. But here it's only one word, and IMO the rest of the sentence makes sense, so why remove the whole sentence?

Answer (score 7):

The whole sentence is redundant. Every question posted to Code Review by default wants: *"any comment about how it may be enhanced (or even corrected if I missed something)"*

In fact, if you did not want that, [then the question would be closed as off-topic.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

[The "thanks" is also routinely removed.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

The edit is a good one.

Comment: Hmm... Not so surprising, finally, and I agree. But what puzzles me is: in fact we can find **a lot** of questions with the same kind of ending mention, and that are not edited though. I think it's difficult for everybody to avoid such (so usual) formulas, even if objectively redundant. As an example, now I must force myself to **not** thank you for the quick response :-)

Comment: Jamal is very efficient atr editing and 'cleaning up' posts here, and he catches a lot of the common problems quickly. He's human, though, and misses things sometimes. If you find a 'thanks', or a redunant part of a question, feel free to edit it yourself (or suggest an edit if your rep is not enough to do it directly). We encourage everyone to improve posts as they see the problems.

Comment: Ok, that's recorded.